# Django Form submit shows Attribute Error 'Form' object has no attribute user

Tags: django, forms, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I m trying to submit a form using classbased view `FormView`

But it is giving the following Error[image]

Here is my `views.py` code for the profile view.

```
class ProfileView(FormView):
    template_name='profile.html'
    form_class = UnregisterMealForm
    context={}
    form=UnregisterMealForm
    @method_decorator(login_required)

    def form_valid(form):
        select_date = request.POST['select_date']
        select_meal = request.POST['meal']
        context['recent'] = "You have succesfully unregistered for "+ select_meal +" on " + select_date 
        return HttpResponse("You have succesfully unregistered for the meal")

    def form_invalid( form):

        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))

    def dispatch(self,*args, **kwargs ):

        if self.request.user.is_active:         
            context = super(ProfileView, self).dispatch( self.request, *args, **kwargs)

            return context                
        else:

            return HttpResponseRedirect('%s?next=%s' % (settings.LOGIN_URL, self.request.path))

    def get_context_data( self, **kwargs):
        form=UnregisterMealForm()
        meals = ['breakfast','lunch','dinner']
        context = {'meals' : meals , 'unregisterform': form}            

        return context
```

Here is my `form`

```
class UnregisterMealForm(forms.Form):
    MEALS = [('breakfast','breakfast'),('lunch','lunch'), ('dinner','dinner')]
    select_date = forms.DateField(widget=DateInput())
    meal = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices=MEALS, attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placehoder':'Choose the Meal' }))
```

Can anybody give me a solution to get rid of this error and succesfully submit my form data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your form and model

Comment: also use login required decorator in dispatch

Comment: garner is correct, and gives the same answer I told you on your previous question: the decorator needs to be in the `dispatch` method, not form_valid.